# Request dialog using facebook

Tags: facebook

I'm using the request dialog to send an application request to my friends.

Now, I want to embed my id, through a URL so when he clicks the invite, it has to
take him to my app and should get a link like this in the address bar in my browser: `apps.facebook.com/test?uid=1111111111`

This uid is my uid, because I sent the invite to my friend.

How to do this?
**Updated on 21/10/2011**

```
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    oauth: true
  });


  function sendRequestToManyRecipients() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function requestCallback(response) {
    // Handle callback here
  }
  function getMultipleRequests(requestIds) {
  FB.api('', {"ids": requestIds }, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: your id is already inside the request_id when they click on the request, you can just read it from there. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ifaour:Updated my question.Where do i put that request_ids in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Request Dialog properties](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), there's the property `data` that can be used to embed your unique identifier.

When a user click the invitation notification, one (or more, if more than one friend invite hime) `request_ids` will be returned. Then you can use the request_ids to query `data`.

**UPDATE**: to put `data` in request:

```
 FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
      data: 'hello'
    }, requestCallback);
```

**UPDATE2**

*The FB invitation has several steps:*

1) This function open a dialog for user (for example, user A) to select friends to invite:

```
 FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
      data: 'hello'
    }, requestCallback);
```

2) After user A invite a friend, says, user B. User B will get a notification on his news feed.

3) User B click into the notification, and get redirected to the canvas page: apps.facebook.com/test?**request_ids=xxxxxx**

4) You use the `request_ids` to retrieve the invitation details, either by javascript

```
function getMultipleRequests(requestIds) {
  FB.api('', {"ids": requestIds }, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
}
```

or by server code(php here, but the same mechanics for other languages):

```
//get the request ids from the query parameter
   $request_ids = explode(',', $_REQUEST['request_ids']);

   //build the full_request_id from request_id and user_id 
   function build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id) {
      return $request_id . '_' . $user_id; 
   }

   //for each request_id, build the full_request_id and delete request  
   foreach ($request_ids as $request_id)
   {
      echo ("reqeust_id=".$request_id."<br>");
      $full_request_id = build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id);  
      echo ("full_request_id=".$full_request_id."<br>");

      try {
         $delete_success = $facebook->api("/$full_request_id",'DELETE');
         if ($delete_success) {
            echo "Successfully deleted " . $full_request_id;}
         else {
           echo "Delete failed".$full_request_id;}
        }          
      catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      echo "error";}
    }
```

Comment: Long:Updated my question.Where do i put that request_ids in my code.

Comment: @user1000990: I have updated the answer. About the request_ids, it will get returned to your call back url as a request parameter.

Comment: Hoang Long: How to pass request parameter and get the sender uid?

Comment: @user1000990: the example code is at the end of the page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ . There's example for php, javascript, and so on.

Comment: Long:I updated my question.i've added that script but that is not giving me request ids

Comment: @user1000990: I think you have misunderstood. I will updated my clarification

Comment: Long:I want those request id and sender id so that i can store it in db

Comment: @user1000990: I have updated the answer. Hope you get a better picture now. You can get all request_id and sender_id by calling the FB api to retrieve inviting information

Comment: Long:How do i send that ids to database

Comment: @user1000990: well, this seems that you are not familiar with FB web development. I will try to explain: please refer to Step 3), in my UPDATE2. At that time, the user will get redirected to your config link (in FB app settings), along with the request_ids. You can catch the request_ids there.

Comment: @user1000990: the request_ids is returned as a GET parameter. Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Long:Atlast got it but how do i get the sender id, using the request id.