# Facebook Request Dialog with data

Tags: facebook

I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832533/request-dialog-using-facebook?answertab=votes#tab-top).

So, I tried it and I put a number in the data property.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Come join me and play at MyWebSite!',
    data: '12345',
    redirect_uri: 'myWebSite'
});
```

I get the `request_ids`, but how do I get the data part (the 12345 number)?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

on server side, you can do something like:(using php here)

```
$request_ids = $_GET['request_ids'];
$request_ids = explode(",", $request_ids);
foreach($request_ids as $request_id)
    {
        $request_object = $facebook->api($request_id);
         if(isset($request_object['data'])) $req_data = $request_object['data']; //$req_data will be '12345' as per your request data set.
       // after getting the data, you may like to delete the request.
           $full_request_id = $request_id."_".$fbid; //$fbid is current user facebook id
          $facebook->api("$full_request_id","DELETE");
     }
```

Comment: Thank You Smita, sorry i just read this, so i'm gonna go and apply it. Thank you very much.

Comment: thank you very much, i hope everybody can see this. Coz it worked. Thank you for the enlightment

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Facebook's documentation too?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/ has more documentation; if a `data` parameter was added in the call to the requests dialog, the same value should also be there when requesting the Request details via the API (i.e. a call to `/REQUEST_ID`)

Comment: hmmmm, this more make sense to me, though i've only read a few part of it. I'll get back to you when i finished reading it

Comment: so i've read it. Basically what i need is ALMOST similar to App to User Request, but UNFORTUNATELY it only work for Canvas App. While mine is a website.

Comment: User to User and App To User requests are only for canvas apps and mobile apps

Comment: Igy, God i'm really really really SORRY. I share this link on Facebook Developers Group and i forgot to turn off the thumbnail. And the link got share with your picture as the thumbnail. I'm really really really sorry

Answer (score 0):

See the facebook developer site documentation for more details
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Note:

`data`:Optional, additional data you may pass for tracking. This will be stored as part of the request objects created. The maximum length is 255 characters.

Comment: I've read it, and it still confuses me. I mean, to get the request_ids. I use the php $_GET method. But it gives me a number that i presume as it is, a request_id. But i didn't get the data part. Or maybe it's already in the request_ids, i just dont know how to extract it